# Firefox won't handle event despite passing through function

Tags: javascript, events, firefox

I'm trying to get a page to have cross browser support, however I keep getting stuck on Mozilla Firefox.  I have IE and Chrome working though.  The code is:

```
function positiontip(e){
   var e = window.event ? event : e;
   if (enabletip) {
      var curX;
      var curY;
      if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
         curX = e.pageX;
         curY = e.pageY;
      } else if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
         curX = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
            + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
         curY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
            + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      }
```

When ever I try to use the code, Firefox console spits out an error that

```
e is undefined "if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {"
```

I have tried calling the function via

```
positiontip();
```

and

```
positiontip(event);
```

But neither are working.
any ideas?

Comment: How do you know e is being passed in properly by the caller? Include the calling code that dispatches the event handler.

Comment: @Toxikman:  No idea.  I thought firefox passes the event to the function when e (or what you call it in the function) is the parameter.

Comment: Yeah can we see the code that calls this function please?

Comment: Nevermind.  The problem was that the function positiontip() was called in another function and the other function was being passed the event.  I had to changed the html to pass the event to showtooltip() [the upper function] that then passed the event to positiontip().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. The problem was that the function positiontip() was called in another function and the other function was being passed the event. I had to changed the html to pass the event to showtooltip() [the upper function] that then passed the event to positiontip().

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `var e = window.event ? event : e;` with `e = e || window.event;`